# Taking input in form and then comparing it with values stored in databse in django

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I was working on a project where the user inputs the answer to the question and then the user input needs to be checked on clicking submit button. If input matches the answer stored in database in the admin portal then it should redirect it to a new page else it should give an error wrong answer.

What's happening is that for every user input i am redirected to the other page. But never shows Wrong Answer even if input other than that in database answer is entered. How do I tackle this?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms    
from .models import Answer    
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist    
class CheckAnswer(forms.Form):    
    your_answer=forms.CharField(label='Answer')    
    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data=super(CheckAnswer,self).clean()    
        response=cleaned_data.get("your_answer")    
        try:
            p = Answer.objects.filter(answer__contains=response)    
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:    
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Answer")
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User=get_user_model()
users=User.objects.all()
class Answer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering= ["-name"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import *
from . import models
from django import forms
from .forms import CheckAnswer
def Arena1(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CheckAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('thanks')
    else:
        form=CheckAnswer()
    return render(request,'levels/arena1.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: This is likely to have all sorts of problems. The most obvious is that `__contains` is case-sensitive (e.g. the correct answer "Yes" will not match the user input "yes"). `__icontains` solves this, but you're still left with code that will interpret the input "a" as a match for the answer "The Spanish Inquisition."

Comment: You can add `if else statement` in your forms.py to raise `validation error` instead of `try & except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model Managers `filter` method does not raise `DoesNotExist`, you should use `Answer.objects.get(answer__contains=response)` to raise `DoesNotExist`, keep in mind that this can also return a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error if there is more than one answer matching your response, `filter` will just return an empty list.

The other option is to use `Answer.objects.filter(answer__contains=response).exists()` and check if it returns true or false.

Comment: Using `get()` instead of `filter(...).exists()` is only an option if there can only ever be one CheckAnswer object that contains the provided response, since it will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` if there's more than one that matches.

Comment: That's a very good point, I'll add this caveat to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for help. This just solves the basic problem..
Is there any way to tackle this..
Suppose level1 is open so the answer of level 1 should only be matched and not that if the user input is present in any of the answers further it would redirect as specified. to be in specific how can answer of each specific question can be checked.
the code is same as above

Comment: I think the concept of pk would be used here.
but how to do it I am completely unaware of . PLS HELP

Comment: Without knowing too much about your models I can't say for certain, but it seems  you may need each Answer to relate to a Question.   You could have a `question` field (such as `question="arena1"`) so then when you check for answers you should check the answer using `Answer.objects.filter(answer__contains=response, question="arena1").exists()`